# Menu driven program in c to perform various operations on an array

Tags: c, arrays

Following is my c program that performs various operations on an array.When i delete any element the delete_ele function deletes and displays the array correctly, but the traverse function displays some garbage value. Eg. If initially i have 4 elements and delete the first element, the delete_ele function will display the remaining 3 elements but the traverse function displays 4 elements(remaining 3 elements along with a garbage value at the end). Please tell me the error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void insert_ele(int i,int ar[],int len){
    int ele, loc;
    printf("\nEnter element to be inserted : ");
    scanf("%d",&ele);
    printf("\nEnter location : ");
    scanf("%d",&loc);
    if(i==19){
        printf("\nOverflow");
    }
    else{
        while(i>=loc){
            ar[i+1]=ar[i];
            i--;
        }
    ar[loc]=ele;
    len++;
    printf("\nNew Array : ");
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        printf("\t%d",ar[i]);
    }
    }
}
void delete_ele(int i,int ar[],int len){
    int loc;
    printf("\nEnter location of element to be deleted : ");
    scanf("%d",&loc);
    if(len==0){
        printf("\nUnderflow");
    }
    else{
        for(i=loc;i<len;i++){
            ar[i]=ar[i+1];
        }
        len--;
        printf("\nNew Array : ");
        for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        printf("\t%d",ar[i]);
        }
    }
}
void find_ele(int i,int ar[],int len){
    int ele, count=0;
    printf("\nEnter element to be searched : ");
    scanf("%d",&ele);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(ar[i]==ele){
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count == 0){
        printf("\nElement does not exist");
    }
    else{
        printf("\nElement found %d times",count);
    }
}
void traverse(int i, int ar[], int len){
    printf("\nTotal number of Elements are : %d",len);
    printf("\nElements are : ");
    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
        printf("\t%d",ar[i]);
    }
}
void main(){
    int ar[20], i=0, len=0, ch;
    char choice;
    clrscr();
    printf("\nEnter number of elements you want to insert : ");
    scanf("%d",&len);
    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
        printf("Enter element %d : ",i);
        scanf("%d",&ar[i]);
    }
    i--;
    label:
    printf("\nPress 1 to insert, 2 to delete, 3 to find any element");
    printf("\n or 4 to traverse the array : ");
    scanf("%d",&ch);
    switch(ch){
        case 1:insert_ele(i, ar, len);
        break;
        case 2:delete_ele(i, ar, len);
        break;
        case 3:find_ele(i, ar, len);
        break;
        case 4:traverse(i, ar, len);
        break;
        default:printf("\nInvalid Option");
        break;
    }
    printf("\nPress y to continue or any other key to quit : ");
    scanf("%s",&choice);
    if(choice=='y' || choice=='Y'){
        goto label;
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in your debugger and examining the state of the variables ? This should take you straight to your bugs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Menu driven program in c to perform various operations on a linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364493/menu-driven-program-in-c-to-perform-various-operations-on-a-linked-list)

Comment: @PaulR Is it duplicate I don't think, Although simple bug to find but marking duplicate is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are decrementing a local variable (`len`) in `delete_ele()`

Try:

```
void delete_ele(int i, int ar[], int *len){
    int loc;
    printf("\nEnter location of element to be deleted : ");
    scanf("%d", &loc);
    if(*len == 0){
        printf("\nUnderflow");
    }
    else{
        for(i=loc; i< (*len - 1); i++){
            ar[i] = ar[i + 1];
        }
        (*len)--;
        printf("\nNew Array : ");
        for(i=0; i<*len; i++){
           printf("\t%d", ar[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

in order to share `len`.

Same for `insert_ele()`

Comment: Sorry I should comment but edited, point is for condition should be `(*len - 1)`

Comment: Ops, sorry Grijesh, I didn't see that, feel free to edit again

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm...

Comment: @rippy check for loop condition should be `*len - 1` else it give array out of index problem when `len = 20`. Also add spaces after `;`

Answer (score 1):

One bug is:  `delete_ele()` function calling undefined behavior due to array index out of range in for-loop when `len` value is `20` (read comments):

```
for(i = loc; i < len; i++){
   ar[i] = ar[i + 1]; 
}  //       ^^^^^^^ out of index for `i = len - 1` 
   // max index can be `len - 1` but when `i = len - 1` 
   // then ar[i + 1] == ar[len] that causes array out-of-index
```

Should be:

```
for(i = loc; i < len-1; i++){ # replaced `len` by `len - 1` 
    ar[i] = ar[i + 1]; 
}
```

And looks similar bug you have in other functions too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `len` in `main` doesn't get updated by `delete_ele` and `insert_ele`. 
You pass `len` to those functions by value. The local copy is then updated inside the respective function, but `len` in main remains unchanged.

One way to correct the problem is to pass `len` by reference (as a pointer) to `delete_ele` and `insert_ele`.